How to query rows with timestamps before today in grafana
How do I perform this kind of query in grafana?
select some_column from some_table where some_datetime < now();

I've made a dashboard variable that's populated from SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
but i can't figure out how to get that into the query in grafana. I'm tempted to make some views in the db for this stuff.

Why is initial query (without any variables) not satisfactorilsatisfactory for you? Also, what seems to be the problem she you use normal syntax $var?

@markalex because i want this to always use the current day and  in the query builder if i choose some_datetime < $var it errors
